# A skill that you have, but has little to no benefit for you

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Most of us have these little things we are able to do, that are a little different or special.  Maybe it is something we mostly use in laid-back social situations, to break the ice and get a laugh.  Beyond that, however, this talent does not do much for us.  It is clearly not anything we would ever list on a resume.  What might you call it?

---

Intended use:

> Mike's family knew he was finally recovering from his injuries when he resumed his _______ of turning everything into a corny pun, which made his nurses laugh.

Another possible use:

> Alice: *(sticking out tongue and touching it to tip of nose)* Tada!
>
> Bob: Wow.  Impressive.
>
> Alice: Thanks, but I know that with this _______ and a dollar I can get a cup of coffee.

---

Candidates considered:

**Hobby**:  On the contrary, your hobby can be of tremendous benefit to you.  It is fun for you, releives your stress, and lets you have a sense of accomplishment. (reject)

**Antic(s)**: For me, this has too much of a connotation that you only do the thing to create havoc or to tease another person. (near-miss)

**Trick**:  In the absence of other options, this is what I might go with.  However, this still doesn't quite sound right when I read it back. (debatable near-miss).

Despite this, feel free to propose any of these as answers if you can cite definitions and usage examples that refute my objections.

---

Final word:  This is tagged with both [single-word-requests](/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) and [phrase-requests](/questions/tagged/phrase-requests).  All things being equal, a single word will win.  However, where a [short multi-word phrase](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7435/13804) tells the story better than one word, then so be it.

Comment: *Useless talent*? https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnUselessTalents/

Comment: Nowadays, getting a cup of coffee for a dollar would be the big trick there!

Comment: "Hidden talents" often (though not always!) fit into this category.

Comment: My useless talent is posting upvoteable comments on Stack Exchange questions.

Comment: David Letterman used to call them "Stupid Human Tricks".  (A callback to his early segments called "Stupid Pet Tricks".)

Comment: *Antics* is fine: "foolish, outrageous, or amusing behavior." It does not mean *shenanigans* : "silly or high-spirited behavior; mischief." (both from Google)

Comment: non-performing skillsets

Comment: Related but not identical: [Underwater Basket Weaving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_basket_weaving)

Comment: its a good question, I don't know an SWR for "useless talent".

Comment: "Untapped potential", is a phrase I commonly hear to refer to this type of attribute in a person.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Perhaps an English term borrowed from Yiddish, *[schtick](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=S5408600)* (or *shtick*, or *shtik*)

> A characteristic attribute, talent, or trait that is helpful in securing recognition or attention: *waiters in tropical attire are part of the restaurant's shtick.*

*American Heritage Dictionary*

The term is often applied to a comedian's signature style or routine.

Comment: I have never heard this used in the UK.

Comment: @Ian Depends where you live and who you mix with. I've heard it plenty of times

Comment: As @CaptainCranium suggests in his answer, the term *schtick* "generally connotes something like a trademark behaviour that pretty much anyone could reproduce... but they would just look like cheap imitators."

Comment: I'd just use behavior.

Comment: IMO, while valid, I think it is reasonable to wonder if the idiom would be equally accessible in other forms of english. I seriously doubt that in english speaking countries with no jewish culture prevalence this word is even known.

Comment: @Joum While I cannot speak to its use in other countries, the term has wide acceptance in the US, even in locales with limited numbers of people of Jewish background.

Comment: @bib but that resonates with jewish culture prevalence in the US as a whole, not just in some locales. For instance, should you go to Kenya, I doubt any kenyan would recognise the word. But it's valid, I just think the scope isn't that wide, and since it is, as you put it correctly, a *borrowed* word, it may not be the most adequate solution. Good job, though! :)

Comment: I'd agree with others that this is probably the wrong answer if you're talking to an international audience. I've never heard it before.

Comment: @Avrohom With a name like yours, I'd be shocked to find out you've never heard *schtick*. // OP, schtick is good, but rarely (if ever) has "useless" connotation. At the worse, it describes repetitive behaviour that is highly specific to a person and makes them stand out in some way.

Comment: @A.S. Hee hee, kinda gives it away eh?

Comment: @A.S. While I agree that schtick can be used neutrally, it often has a dismissive quality, and I have rarely heard it in a really positive tone. I agree it does not universally suggest *useless*, although it often suggests a shallow performance of little value

Comment: I love "schtick", and it's a poor writer who doesn't occasionally extend his reader's vocabulary!  But I think it means more than a "party trick".  Which is my best suggestion.

Answer (score 99):

I'm not sure it matches your first example, but I feel it matches your description and second example, I'd suggest **party trick**.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://Oxford%20Dictionaries) describes it as

> A trick such as might be performed at a party for entertainment; an unusual act regarded as one's speciality.

Comment: Or *party **piece***, which is [significantly more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+party+piece%2Chis+party+trick&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20party%20piece%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20party%20trick%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Being from the [UK and a child of the 90's "trick" is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+party+piece%2Chis+party+trick&year_start=1940&year_end=1999&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20party%20piece%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20party%20trick%3B%2Cc0) to me than "piece", but "piece" certainly fits.

Comment: Hey... I'm a (UK) child of the 60s, and I'll support your support for 'party trick' as an informal thing that works as a signature.

Comment: @FumbleFingers...  The term 'party piece' tends to mean something practised and relatively formal, e.g. being able to whistle 'The Star Spangled Banner' while somersaulting backwards through a hoop.  A 'party trick' is more like dislocating both shoulders and climbing into a washing machine.

Comment: I think that apparent recent upsurge for ***trick*** is just an artefact of the small sample size in the *British English (2009)* corpus. It's not there in the broader *British English* I linked to, nor in *English (2009), English Fiction (2009)* or *English Fiction (2009)*. But they're both perfectly idiomatic BrE usages, almost completely interchangeable, and much more common in BrE than AmE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  No.  These two usages are different.

Comment: @Captain Cranium: I did say *almost* completely interchangeable. Though I must say I expect *most* speakers tend to just use the version they're most familiar with, rather than consciously applying the distinction you make (which strikes me as being based on your post-hoc reasoning, rather than knowledge of a broad range of actual usages in context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  You are using the word 'party' to confuse two things. Your graph shows the increasing availability of both expressions over time. That does not help the OP.

A party piece (e.g. a recital of music or poetry, or a bit of ice-sculpting or wardrobe-climbing) is selected to impress family, patrons, sponsors, etc..

A party trick, on the other hand, is a weird thing that you can do. This is what the OP is asking about.

Casual access to irrelevant online stats has nothing to do with real usage. If you can do that with your eyes shut, however, then that would count as a party trick.

Comment: @Captain Cranium: To repeat - that's just *your* opinion. You're unlikely to find any reference sources to substantiate your position. I'm sure I've used (and *heard*) both versions many times every year for decades. As it happens, I'm more likely to use ***trick*** in extremely figurative condemnatory contexts *(He did his usual party trick of getting drunk and disgracing himself)*, but *overall* I'm pretty sure I use *piece* more often. Casual access to online stats doesn't "prove" much, I admit. But neither do unverifiable claims that there are "correct" and "incorrect" contextual usages.

Comment: No, thank you.  I got no further use for this guy, and I have tried to protect the OP from his or her insistence on pushing an unfounded opinion and an argumentative style of deploying arbitrary 'evidence' that SE quite correctly resists. This person is actively obstructing the OP's question, in order to make a personal stand. That is OK, however: JS Mill clearly shows how angry people being wrong hand calm people the chance to think carefully about why we think what we think. In that spirit, let's also help Flumbs to be calm about productive discussion.

Comment: Just to add a little more sourcing to @CaptainCranium’s position, the [full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138347) (subscription-only, unfortunately) agrees that *party piece* and *party trick* are related but not the same: **Party trick**  n. a trick such as might be performed at a party for entertainment; an unusual act regarded as one's speciality; cf. *party piece* n.  // **Party piece**  n. a piece of music or other act performed by a person on a special occasion; an unusual trick, feat, etc., for which one is renowned; cf. *party trick* n.

Comment: Or parlor trick.

Comment: "Parlor trick" is often prefixed with "cheap" and in that case has a negative connotation of being patently deceptive as part of a con job. You might also describe what OP is asking for as a bar trick. (Maybe they have "pub trick" on the other side of the Atlantic?)

Comment: Being from the US and a child of the '80s, I'd go for party trick or parlor trick. Since parlor is a bit of an old-fashioned term, that would make it slightly more lame (like Alice's example), whereas a party trick might be kind of cool, but not that cool, and a parlor trick I feel like people will get bored with it, it *might* be amusing one time, and eventually annoying when repeated over and over again, and may induce eye rolls among those familiar with the subject's enjoyment of performing said trick.

Answer (score 29):

What do you think about **gimmick**? Though not always something that you *do*, a gimmick has the connotation of being a feature which superficially attracts attention or but has no real or practical value.

**gimmick** (n)

a method or trick that is used to get people's attention or to sell something

Answer (score 11):

Although not exactly something one might *do* (at least not always willingly), I think **[quirk](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quirk?s=t)** fits your description:

> a peculiarity of action, behavior, or personality; mannerism;

in [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quirk?s=t)

Answer (score 11):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but *knack* might fit.

> Mike's family knew he was finally recovering from his injuries when he resumed his knack of turning everything into a corny pun, which made his nurses laugh.

In Alice's case, she would have a knack for performing odd physical feats.

[m-w definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knack)

Comment: But suppose Bob has a knack for fixing bugs in computer programs. It could be highly beneficial to him.

Comment: This strikes me as the most neutral descriptor, in contrast to gift/aptitude (positive) or shtick/peculiarity/gimmick/routine (which can be interpreted as slightly negative i.e. 'played out')

Answer (score 9):

Referencing the movie [Planet Terror](http://planetterror.wikia.com/wiki/Useless_Talents), I would use "useless talent". Which seems also adopted by [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnUselessTalents/), but certainly not by any dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

As with many words, the tone used may be all that's needed to convey some sarcastic disrespect for that talent. I don't think there exists a single-word that implies a useless talent (and having the ability to make people laugh is never a wasted effort!).

The "Shtick" to me implies a routine for comedic effect - not neccessarily just a physical capacity.

So I'd probably just go with any of the synonyms for "**talent**"

**gift**

**aptitude**.

hmm.... how about: "**peculiarity**", implying an odd characteristic?

Answer (score 3):

My instinctive response (as explained in related comments) was **party trick**, meaning a fairly personal ability that others would find hard to replicate.  Farting the alphabet, say, or reciting an obscure novel backwards.

(The term '*party piece*', which some seem to think equivalent, refers to much more competitive acts to impress, related to reproducible repertoire.)

On the other hand, if the act in question is primarily one of memorable self-promotion then the term **shtick** can apply.  That generally connotes something like a trademark behaviour that pretty much anyone could reproduce... but they would just look like cheap imitators.  Examples would include Tommy Cooper's shrugging 'Juz like that', or Steve Martin's arrow through the head.

Comment: This seems to be a restatement of the other two preexisting answers.

Comment: @stannius Not at all.  My post-in-progress was delayed by someone arguing about something from trivial opinion.  Here, I offered a succinct comparison, with examples, of two complementary ideas bearing on OP's actual question, with a sidelight on a potential distraction.  I am happy that others have also mentioned those ideas individually, and I would have retired my post entirely if I had thought that existing contributions had entirely overtaken this one.

Answer (score 2):

Though *Party Trick* or *Party Piece* fits the description well, they don't quite fit the examples completely naturally.

You could use [*'routine'*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/routine?s=t) in the examples to great effect.

> **Routine** - noun
>
> 6 - an individual act, performance, or part of a performance, as a song or dance, given regularly by an entertainer: 
>   a comic routine; a dance routine.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Though the dictionary definition given above fairly strongly references an actual act or performance, the term is also very commonly used to imply a contrived action *performed* by someone *as if* it was an act or performance in the classic sense of the word. Something of a synonym for 'party trick' and 'schtick'.

E.g. *Alice: Thanks, but I know that with this routine and a dollar I can get a cup of coffee*

Answer (score 2):

A word that sprang to my mind is ***specialty***.

While this words is often used in serious contexts, such as medicine, mathematics, or cooking, it can  also be used tongue-in-cheek to refer to such "talents" as you allude to:

> *Mike resumed his **specialty** of turning everything into a corny pun, which made his nurses laugh*.
>
> *With this **specialty** and a dollar I can get a cup of coffee*.

Those seem like fairly acceptable usages (especially the first one). As for other places where I've seen the word used in a similar fashion, I found some interesting quotes:

#### • ***My specialty is detached malevolence*.**

<sup>Alice Roosevelt Longworth, who also quipped: "If you can't say
something good about someone, sit right here by me."</sup>

#### • ***My specialty is two things: music or really strange stories.***

<sup>Malik Bendjelloul, filmmaker and director</sup>

#### • ***My specialty is sticking my heart in places that it doesn’t belong.***

<sup>A blogger named [Elly](http://creatingaquietmind.tumblr.com/post/36915931558/mynameiselly-my-specialty-is-sticking-my-heart)</sup>

#### •  ***Practical jokes were his specialty**.  Even as a small child, he had delighted in trickery and as he grew up, the jokes became more sophisticated.*

<sup>From the book *Underground: Tales of Hacking, Madness and Obsession on the Electronic Frontier* by S. Dreyfus and J. Assange</sup>

And of course, the classic last line of [*The Open Window*](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/OpeWin.shtml) by Saki:

#### •  ***Romance at short notice was her specialty*.**

Comment: Impetuous downvoting is someone's specialty...

Answer (score 0):

Although such activities would seem to fit in Oxford Dictionary’s second definition of a “[diversion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/diversion)":
“An activity that diverts the mind from tedious or serious concerns; a recreation or pastime: ‘our chief diversion was reading’,”

“diversion” would not, however, work well in either of your examples.
(on the other hand, although “habit” would “sound good” at least in your first example, it wouldn’t be fitting at all for the notion that you seek)

Working from the above sense #2 of “diversion,” however, I think “[sideshow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sideshow)” could capture the general notion you seek and could work in both of your examples as well:

“Mike … resumed his sideshow of …”

“…with this sideshow and a dollar I can get a cup of coffee.”

**[sideshow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sideshow)**
:  a minor show offered in addition to a main exhibition (as of a circus [**or resume?**])
2 :  an incidental **diversion** or spectacle
(from ‘Merriam-Webster)

(example of “sideshow” used as a “[impromptu] comedy routine” found in [‘Letters from My Sister: On Life, Love and Hair Removal’](https://books.google.com/books?id=L8ec1dRGQuEC&pg=PA136&dq=%22sideshow%22+%22party+trick%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiihq3um7TLAhXFuIMKHXvaB2EQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22sideshow%22%20%22party%20trick%22&f=false) by Eve Lederman, Faye Lederman at ‘Google Books’)

Answer (score 0):

How about 'forté'?

This word implies that the talent is a natural skill, that it is fun for, and comes easily to, the protagonist, does not necessarily bring him anything, it's just something he likes to do - that it is a kind of habit, or something he 'falls into' - like a 'groove'.

Forté.

Some synonyms are also listed here - métier, strong suit, bent, gift, strength, specialty:

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=meaning+forte&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

I would use 'forté' for your first example, and 'talent' or 'gift' for your second.

Comment: Why would having a *forté* be of little value? Why would "talent" be of little use? Normally, talents describe a special or a natural ability that others may find extremely difficult to do *well*. I don't think anyone is going to say the ability to touch their nose with the tip of their tongue is a "forte" or a "talent" of theirs. "Ironically" maybe, but that's switching the meanings in a humorous way, which you don't mention.

Comment: Forté has a sense of meaning 'habit', which I think fits well. I said it 'does not necessarily bring him anything' not, that it is valueless. It would be difficult not to be ironic in either of the given examples. But maybe that's my forté...

Answer (score -2):

**Affectation**
-can mean an  adopted way of speaking or behaving, implies an attitude deliberately assumed in order to impress others.

Example:

Bob's silly French accent is just an affectation.

Comment: "Thanks, but I know that with this *affectation* and a dollar I can get a cup of coffee"? I don't think that fits into the example sentences in the question.